# Combine grep with and & or logic

Tags: python, bash, grep

I am trying to convert the following code which is written in python to use cat | grep instead of opening a file.

The original code:

```
LOG_NAME="/raft/log/{}{}{}_{}_Rx_flow.log".format(NTIME.tm_year,str(NTIME.tm_mon).zfill(2),str(NTIME.tm_mday).zfill(2),str(NTIME.tm_hour).zfill(2))
print time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") + " Log file name, RX restart, is: " + LOG_NAME
print time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") + " ERRTIMEMIN value: " + ERRTIMEMIN + " RXRESTART message value: " + RXRESTART

LINK_LOG_FILE = open(LOG_NAME, "r")
ISRXRESTART=0
for REPline in LINK_LOG_FILE:
  ***if RXRESTART in REPline and (ERRTIMEMIN in REPline or ERRTIMEMIN1 in REPline) and ISRXRESTART==0:***
     #Link restarted - correct behaviour.
     print time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") + " RX restarted - This is correct behaviour"
     ISRXRESTART=1
```

I have to delete the line which opens the file and change the following line with the `***    ***` to something with cat and grep
for example:

```
os.popen("sshpass -p  ssh root@"+self.ipaddr+" cat "+LOG_NAME+"  | egrep `"+device_start+" "+ERRTIMEMIN+`").read().strip()
```

But I don't know how to combine or & and in the same grep

Comment: @fedorquiI said exactly what I want in the last part of the question

Comment: Better include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

"OR" can be simulated by simply grepping multiple patterns at once:

```
egrep -E 'thing1|thing2' <file.txt
```

-E tells egrep to use extended regex.

To my knowledge there is no "AND" operator in grep but again can be simulated by grepping for patterns in both forward and backward order.

```
egrep -E 'thing1.*thing2|thing2.*thing1' <file.txt
```

Use `-v` for "NOT".

```
egrep -E 'thing1' <file.txt | egrep -v 'thing2'
```

This will find everything with "thing1" then grab only the stuff without "thing2".

Hope this helped.